# how to get audio absolute path in Android using createChooser

Tags: android

I want to get a absolute path from URI path using createChooser. What I have to do? If you know a solution that solve this problem, pls, inform me. by the way,
URI path display follow path:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A38
```

Normal path display follow path:

```
/document/audio:38
```

Here is My Code:

```
 public void set_music_path(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "음악을 선택해주세요."), 1);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int req, int res, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(req, res, data);

    Uri uri = data.getData();
    Toast.makeText(this, uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, uri.getPath().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I'm a Korean student, so there are some grammar errors. 
if there are grammar errors, overlook my faults

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to realize that `createChooser()` has nothing to do with the format of the `Uri` that you get back from your `startActivityForResult()` call. Any `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activity can hand back whatever valid `Uri` it wants to. You could get that sort of `Uri` from your `startActivityForResult()` call, even if you left off the `createChooser()` part.

Second, you need to realize that a `Uri` is not a file. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activities can return a `Uri` pointing to anything that the activities want.

*If* the scheme of the `Uri` happens to be `file`, then `getPath()` will be a filesystem path, pointing to a file that (presumably) you could access.

If the scheme is `content` — as is the case here — then the `Uri` can point to *anything*:

- A file on external storage that you could access
- A file on removable storage that you cannot access
- A file on internal storage of another app, that you cannot access
- An asset of another app, which is not a file
- A value from a `BLOB` column of a database, which is not a file
- A value that is generated on the fly, the way that this Web page is, which is not a file
- Content that will be streamed from the Internet, which is not a file on the device
- And so on

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` (and perhaps `openOutputStream()`) to work with the content identified by the `Uri`.

If you happen to be working with some third-party library that requires a `File`, switch to a better library that can work with an `InputStream`.

If you cannot find a better library, you will have to use the `InputStream` to copy the bytes of the content to some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), then use that file.

Comment: @박광유: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Documents/Consumer https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Documents/Durable

Comment: hey! I want to know what you say. how to use InputStream??